# Terraform: emr_cluster: Auto terminate

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, terraform

I am using terraform to create emr_cluster and AWS CLI to add steps (Unless TF offers a way to add steps but I couldn't find it).

I have set `keep_job_flow_alive_when_no_steps` to "**false**" in the terraform script. But when I run it, the "**Auto-terminate**" option is still set to "No" when checking the AWS console and the cluster runs indefinitely.

Is there a way to set auto-terminate using terraform (or even through CLI after creation)?  Or, am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this option in resource `aws_emr_cluster`

```
termination_protection = false
```

Any differences?

Comment: Thanks! I do have those 2 lines

    
  termination_protection = false
  keep_job_flow_alive_when_no_steps = false

Comment: The termination_protection switch works for Termination Protection when I flip it.